# How to use Publisher Subscriber with Channels

Tags: c#

I am trying out a new pattern called "Publisher and Subscriber with Channel". Most of our application is service based or console based so I do not need the API yet. This is how I implement it: I am following this tutorial:

> https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Jz8ebpd7mvQ

```
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using System.Threading.Channels;
namespace PubSubWithChannelInConsole
{
    internal class Program
    {
        private static OrderEntryPoint? _orderEntryPoint;
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            SetupEngine();

            repeat:

            Console.WriteLine("Say something");

            var whatsSaid = Console.ReadLine();

            _orderEntryPoint!.SendMessageToOrderProcessor(whatsSaid!);

            goto repeat;
        }

        private static void SetupEngine()
        {
            var serviceCollection = new ServiceCollection();
            serviceCollection.AddSingleton(Channel.CreateBounded<string>(100));
            serviceCollection.AddHostedService<OrderProcessor>();
            serviceCollection.AddSingleton<OrderEntryPoint>();
            
            var serviceProvider = serviceCollection.BuildServiceProvider(validateScopes: true);
            _orderEntryPoint = serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<OrderEntryPoint>();
        }
    }
}

using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;
using System.Threading.Channels;
namespace PubSubWithChannelInConsole
{
    public class OrderProcessor : IHostedService
    {
        private readonly Channel<string> channel;

        public OrderProcessor(Channel<string> channel)
        {
            this.channel = channel;
        }

        public Task StartAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            return Task.Factory.StartNew(async () =>
            {
                await Console.Out.WriteLineAsync("HELLO!");
                while (!channel.Reader.Completion.IsCompleted)
                {
                    var response = await channel.Reader.ReadAsync();
                    Console.WriteLine($@"You said {response}");
                }
            });
        }

        public Task StopAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            return Task.CompletedTask;
        }
    }
}

using System.Threading.Channels;
namespace PubSubWithChannelInConsole
{
    public interface IOrderEntryPoint
    {
        void SendMessageToOrderProcessor(string message);
    }

    public class OrderEntryPoint : IOrderEntryPoint
    {
        private readonly Channel<string> channel;

        public OrderEntryPoint(Channel<string> channel)
        {
            this.channel = channel;
        }

        public async void SendMessageToOrderProcessor(string message)
        {
            await channel.Writer.WriteAsync(message);
        }
    }
}
```

This runs fine without any error but whatever I input in my Program.cs is not being reflected on the OrderProcess.cs

Comment: On the side note: using while loop is better than `goto`

Comment: @Chetan you're right. But that's not the one causing the issue. Any ideas?

Comment: One thing I observed is `IHostedService` is not started. Hence it looks like `await channel.Reader.ReadAsync()` is not executed at all.

Comment: The OrderProcessor inherits from IHostedService so I'm thinking that it is started already. In the tutorial, this is how he started it. Please see my edit for the link.